# Multiple Step OLE DB Operation Generated error when Connecting from Access 2013 to SQL Server 2017 from same network domain PC

Tags: sql-server, vba, string, ms-access

I have a application which front end application is Access 2013 in  client PC and have SQL server 2017 Installed in Server PC. When I try connecting server PC from client PC MS access 2013 application, it throws Error of

> "Multiple Step OLE DB Operation Generated error"

and connection is not established.

I am using the below connection string for accessing the SQL server from the remote network PC.

```
strConn = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=DT-AVAYA-SVR\SQLEXPRESS;DATABASE=Admin15;Trusted_Connection=true"
```

The above connection string is working fine with the same server PC.

I had tried changing the `Trusted connection = False` as well as `Integrated Security = SSPI`. But I am facing the same error.

Comment: please provide your code that throws an error.

Comment: Do the linked tables work? I would think before attempting all kinds of coding and what not, one should try and get the linked tables working, since no code is involved. And are you using sql logons, and providing a correct password,or are you using windows authentications. Also, since you going to work with SQL server, then you quite much need to install SSMS (SQL management studio) on your client side machine. So, can you connect from SSMS?

Comment: @ Krish KM, Thanks for your immediate response. the error code is 2147217887. Please help

Comment: @ Albert D. Thanks . I have not tested the linked table . I have created the data base in SQL server with Windows authentication . I have not created SQL logins on the server and also the SSMS is not installed on the client machine. I recently upgraded my access database to SQL hence I would like to continue the access as front end application of my DB. In this case do I need to Install SSMS in client side machine ?